# What is the purpose of new() when defining a generic?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand generics. Here's an example of one:

```
   public static bool CreateTableIfNotExist<T>(this CloudTableClient tableStorage, string entityName)
        where T : TableServiceEntity, new()
    {
        bool result = tableStorage.CreateTableIfNotExist(entityName);

        return result;
    }
```

I have a couple of questions. Firstly, what's the purpose of new() in the definition. My other question is, how can I use this generic. There's an example here:

```
_tableStorage.CreateTableIfNotExist<MembershipRow>(_tableName);
```

But i don't understand. What really is the purpose of this generic? Can't I just do the same thing without the generic?

```
_tableStorage.CreateTableIfNotExist("MyNewTable");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a generic type constraint stating that the type must have a public parameterless constructor.

```
myCloudTableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist<TypeWithPublicParameterlessConstructor>("Customers");
```

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

The main use of this is to allow the generic code to *construct* an instance of `T`, as opposed to `default(T)` - something you may often see. Unfortunately, there is no constraint support for anything other than a public parameterless constructor, when it comes to constraining on constructors.

**Update:** looking at the code you have updated, the generic isn't ever used so in this case it has no purpose. A common tactic for generics on extension methods is to support generic extension methods.

```
public static bool Equals<T>(this T self, T other) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return self.Equals(other);
}
```

**Update 2:** in your example of *not* specifying the type constraint, this would only work if the type constraint [could be inferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) by the compiler based on usage... I'm not sure what would happen in your case, but I'd guess it wouldn't compile.

Comment: thus, being an example of a generic type _constraint_

Answer (score 1):

It's the [new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx). It means only types that have a public constructor that takes no arguments can be the type argument for the generic type.

so a class like this:

```
public class Xyz{
  public string HelloWorld;
}
```

could be used with that function, but this class:

```
public class Abc{
  pulblic string HelloWorld;
  pulbic Abc(string hello){
    HelloWorld = hello;
  } 
}
```

could not, as it doesn't have the required constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`T` will get replaced by the type you specify in the `<>`, this means if you left out `new`, it would supply a `Type` and not an instance to `InitializeTableSchemaFromEntity`